# deploy:mode:set production taking too much time

Tags: magento2, production-mode

I did a `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production` on magento 2 [snappy 4000 vps](https://www.hostgator.com/vps-hosting), it's taking about 3h and still not done.

Is it normal?

4 GB RAM
2 Cores CPU
165 GB Disk Space
2 TB Bandwidth

Aren't those specs enough for magento?

Comment: enable verbose mode, check logs and strace proccess. probably issue with magento, not server.

Comment: @MagenX wow! that'd be strange! Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not normal.

Normally process takes minutes.

Try with no memory limit and show errors.

`php -d display_errors=1 -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`

Your spec is reasonable.  I would recommend 4 cores and around 10GB RAM for Magento.  But ultimately will depend on the concurrent users your site is going to get.  That's fine for around 5 - 10 concurrent users.

Disk space is fine.  Bandwidth is fine.

Comment: Outside the scope of the question, do you recommend any hosting provider? I explained my situation here https://www.reddit.com/r/Magento/comments/bxicoe/magento_2_hosting_recommendation/

Comment: Out of Linode, digital ocean, azure, AWS - I've only used AWS. But I've not used their support. In terms of performance AWS no issues with performance.  Easy to upscale. I've heard positive things about Linode in terms of performance.  But honestly I don't know on a personal level.

Comment: Will they offer support if I pay them on a case by case basis you think or do I need to subscribe to their business plan from day one? Btw if you know another option not included in my list please let me know.

Comment: We've been most impressed with OVH

Comment: Oh that's my teenage days favorite. Really? Good support and magento support?

Comment: Magento is fast. Not used support yet. We've got a couple of good sys admin guys plus I know a bit myself so generally we solve server problems ourselves. Plus we use services like uptime robot to monitor. Uptime robot can integrate with slack. You can get slack of phone. So you know on your phone within minutes if your site has problems. Which is good for business. Bad for stress levels.

Comment: haha! that's awesome!

Answer (score 1):

By Default while setting the production mode the code will get compiled which may increase the time. try to skip compillation while setting production mode and compile afterward.

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation

which will skip the compilation and once the application is set to production compile.

which may resolve your issue.

Comment: Can you provide the command to start compilation afterward?